# Can't move files to a folder in Finder

Tags: macos, finder, filesystem, filevault

Did clean install of Yosemite. In Finder I can't move files to a folder. I must authenticate almost all move operations. After entering password the file is not moved, but copied instead. Apple is not much help. I have been told I have created an encrypted volume and have to bring in computer. I don't buy it. Another consultant said I need to turn off FileVault and unencrypt volume, but FileVault is already off. Anybody familiar with this problem?

```
Clarks-Mac-Pro:~ clarkland$ ls -leO
total 0
drwx------+  5 clarkland  staff  -       170 Apr 15 09:05 Desktop
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+  6 clarkland  staff  -       204 Feb 28 18:32 Documents
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+ 11 clarkland  staff  -       374 Apr  8 02:51 Downloads
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------@ 16 clarkland  staff  -       544 Apr 15 09:05 Dropbox
drwx------@ 53 clarkland  staff  hidden 1802 Mar  5 05:07 Library
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+  7 clarkland  staff  -       238 Mar  2 13:58 Movies
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+  4 clarkland  staff  -       136 Feb  8 18:31 Music
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+  9 clarkland  staff  -       306 Mar  2 13:58 Pictures
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwxr-xr-x+  5 clarkland  staff  -       170 Nov 26 16:24 Public
 0: group:everyone deny delete
```

Created a new administrative user (Fairy Princess), as suggested. It has the same problem.

```
Clarks-Mac-Pro:~ fairyprincess$ ls -leO
total 0
drwx------+  3 fairyprincess  staff  -  102 Apr 15 09:52 Desktop
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+  3 fairyprincess  staff  -  102 Apr 15 09:52 Documents
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+  3 fairyprincess  staff  -  102 Apr 15 09:52 Downloads
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+ 41 fairyprincess  staff  - 1394 Apr 15 09:59 Library
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+  3 fairyprincess  staff  -  102 Apr 15 09:52 Movies
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+  3 fairyprincess  staff  -  102 Apr 15 09:52 Music
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+  3 fairyprincess  staff  -  102 Apr 15 09:52 Pictures
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwxr-xr-x+  5 fairyprincess  staff  -  170 Apr 15 09:52 Public
```

Comment: This doesn't sound like a FileVault-related problem, more like file permissions got messed up somehow. Are there any particular files/folders are you having trouble with? Also, please run the Terminal utility, enter `ls -leO`, and add the output as an edit to your question (and use the the "{}" button to format it as code, so we can see the formatting).

Comment: If you not already have it create a new user and try with that.

Comment: You have a strange ACL that is denying delete privileges to the group "everyone" which includes your user. After your clean install, did you restore from a backup of some sort?

Comment: This was a clean install. No restore. I had tried an upgrade to Mavericks which was a total catastrophe. So I cleaned off the partition and did a clean install of Yosemite.

Answer (score 2):

Much ado about nothing. Here is the solution. Open Info box for the Partition. Go down to Sharing and Permissions. Unlock with password. Add entry for the administrative account you are in - uh oh - it is set to read only. Change to read and write. Problem solved. Everyone I talked to, including Apple, who wanted me to bring the computer in to the store, led me to believe this was some weird problem due to installation, so I never bothered to check for the OBVIOUS.
[image]

Comment: All due respect, it **is** a weird problem if it was a fresh install and you didn't restore any users from Time Machine or another backup. They may not have been assuming that it was serious, and it would have likely been obvious to a tech as soon as s/he laid eye on it, but it's a strange problem to have spontaneously develop.

Comment: Absolutely, it is weird. I have never had problems with a clean system install from Apple ever. I am not much of a system admin person, but something still doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

btw, on my OS X installation, my user account doesn't have *any* designated privileges on the root of the hard drive.